# Select query with "Join" is ignoring where clause

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am fetching data from two tables using query with `WHERE` clause. Query is working fine in local `xampp` but when I try to run same query in online `phpmyadmin` then it showing all available result(instead of filtering with WHERE clause). In other words, in online `phpmyadmin`, it's completing ignoring the `WHERE` clause like it's not even present in query, and showing all results.

Why it is not working online? Any idea?

```
SELECT * FROM `customers` E 
JOIN `customer plans` D ON (E.ID = D.`Cust ID`) 
WHERE E.`Email` = 'abc1002' 
OR E.`Phone` = 'abc1002' 
OR E.`Case ID` = 'abc1002' 
OR D.`Customer ID` = 'abc1002'
```

Comment: Are you getting any error ?

Comment: Possibly the where condition is working and all the rows satisfy the where conditions do you have examples where that is not the case?And it would help if you added the table definitions.

Comment: @sachinshah No, m not getting any errors.

Comment: @p.salmon All where clause is not satisfying condition because same query running fine in localhost xampp with same table and same data in table.

Comment: @Rishabh can you make a http://www.sqlfiddle.com/ for it ?

Comment: @vatev Never try that before but let me see what I can do. Right now I don't have access to DB coz m home now. But will try to make it tomorrow :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try below - using OR condition within parenthesis

```
SELECT * FROM `customers` E JOIN `customer plans` D 
ON (E.ID = D.`Cust ID`) 
where 
(E.`Email` = 'abc1002' OR E.`Phone` = 'abc1002' OR E.`Case ID` = 'abc1002' OR D.`Customer ID` = 'abc1002')
```

Comment: It is also showing same result (working in local but not online. For additional info, "customer plan" table's one column is foreign key of "customers" table, if that info helps to find issue.

Comment: @Rishabh, please provide sample data and your expected output in question - it would be helpful for right answer

Comment: Here is the [link](http://homewi-fi.net/panel/tables.zip) of both table sql files. See if this works in your phpmyadmin. In my case, it's working in local but not online.

Comment: Who knows what the zip file in the link contains - there is zero chance that I will download and open it.(even if I did have and unzip utility installed)

Comment: @p.salmon If you afraid of zip files then I can give link of direct sql files too, so it can be tested. I made zip coz there were 2 sql files. So, let me know if you are comfortable with direct sql file link. I can arrange that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this type of join:

```
select E.*,D.*
from `customers` E , `customer plans` D
where E.ID = D.`Cust ID` and
(E.`Email` = 'abc1002' OR E.`Phone` = 'abc1002' OR E.`Case ID` = 'abc1002' OR D.`Customer ID` = 'abc1002')
```

Comment: Arrggh no don't use implicit joins.

Comment: It is also showing same result (working in local but not online. For additional info, "customer plan" table's one column is foreign key of "customers" table, if that info helps to find issue.

Comment: Why don't use implicit joins?